# New zero sized sphinx index

Tags: sphinx

I have just added a new index in sphinx server where mysql is running on local server, sphinx quires to local mysql, it searches  data but index is zero sized,

sing config file '/usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf'...

indexing index 'test'...

collected 861000 docs, 0.0 MB

collected 932575 docs, 0.0 MB

total 932575 docs, 0 bytes

total 479.180 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 1946.18 docs/sec

total 0 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg

total 4 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.1 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg

rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=5545).

please help

Comment: Do you actully have any **fields** defined in the index ?

Comment: yes, i have defined filters. but when i disabled some of filters it was getting results and making files with 23MB, previously it was creating .new.sp* files. it was quite strange for me

Comment: It might help to actully include your source defintioon (but remove your database credientais!)

Comment: if that was the case then why it was calculation docs and just not getting data in files?

Comment: I suspect you have attributes, but no fields - actual full-text data to index.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved after restarting sphinx service and .new.sp* files which sphinx created also gone after restarting sphinx.